# How much space is needed on iPhone to sync with iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

I specifically added space to iCloud to free up space on my iPhone. But there is such a synchronization error in the photo app.

> Syncing with iCloud Paused. Not Enough iPhone Storage

Storage optimization enabled. The iPhone 8 uses 61.7 GB of 64 GB. About 40 GB of photos have been uploaded to the iCloud about 1 year ago, more than 100 GB are free in the iCloud.
[image]